# jQuery slider want to add arrow to my slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider

This is my jQuery slider code and I want to add right arrow and left arrow for manually sliding in slider what should i do?
If possible give me example or code for that. Thank You

```js
  $(window).load(function() {

    var i = 0;

    var images = ['../images/mainbanner.jpg', '../images/index.jpg'];

    var image = $('#sliderit');

    //Initial Background image setup

    image.css('background-image', 'url(../images/mainbanner.jpg)');

    //Change image at regular intervals

    setInterval(function() {

      image.fadeOut(1000, function() {

        image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i++] + ')');

        image.fadeIn(1000);

      });

      if (i == images.length)
        i = 0;

    }, 3000);

  });
  `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsEne/15/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.sp').first().addClass('active');
$('.sp').hide();    
$('.active').show();

    $('#button-next').click(function(){

    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
                   if ( $('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
        $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
        }
        else{
        $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();


    });

       $('#button-previous').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
           if ( $('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
        $('.sp').last().addClass('active');
        }
           else{
    $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
           }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();
    });




});
```

You can use the simple one too. Check with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WTer/)

Comment: thanx but i want both manually sliding as well as automatic. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes check with the new link.

Comment: Thanx for that but which value i have give Timeout for autoplay ??

Comment: You can just add    timeout:2,

Comment: Thanx for help I got the idea from your answer I implemented on my code but unfortunately ,it's working on my code.